# Axios post method React. State Redux not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I have problem with `State` in `Redux`
This is my `axios` request

```
case 'REGISTER_USER':{

  var userData = {username: action.payload.username, password : action.payload.password};

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'php/register.php',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: userData
  }).then(function(response) {
    state.error = response.data.errors;
    state.success = response.data.success;
});
    return {state};
    break;
  }//end REGISTER_USER
```

Default `state.error`, `state.success` is empty `array`.
After first click `state.error` is still empty array because axois didn't finish request. After 2nd click everything is fine.

And here i have problem with props:

```
{this.props.error.length>0? <div className="alert alert-danger">{this.props.error[0]}</div>: ''}
```

And store:

```
@connect((store)=>{
  return{
    error: store.app.error,
    success: store.app.success,
  }
})
```

Do u know how i can render `component` with new `Props` after `axios method post` finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have written this code into reducer, the api call should be done inside **Action Dispacher**. After api successfully called you have to dispatch data to reducer. In reducer you should only assign the Data, no API Calls inside reducer.

for e.g.

**Action Dispatcher**

```
export function APIDispatch(data)
{
    return{
        type:'API_DATA_RECD',                
        data:data
    }
}

export function callAPI(){
    return function(dispatch){
         axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'php/register.php',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: userData
          }).then(function(response) {
            state.error = response.data.errors;
            state.success = response.data.success;
            dispatch(APIDispatch(state))
        });

    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
case 'API_DATA_RECD':
    {   
        // you will get data from action.data
    }
```

Comment: This work! If you didn't help me, I would spend the rest of my life at this code :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Axios is making an ajax request asynchronously, in the case REGISTER_USER , the piece of code it's returning the object with the state property right away meanwhile the request is still pending,  that means the object has no meaninful values. You should only return values whenever the request(s) you're making are completed.

Try this:

```
case 'REGISTER_USER':{

  var userData = {username: action.payload.username, password : action.payload.password};

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'php/register.php',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: userData
  }).then(function(response) {
    state.error = response.data.errors;
    state.success = response.data.success;

    return {state}
});
    break;
  }//end REGISTER_USER
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Given action "REGISTER_USER", reducer "app" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined.
I i cant wait with return before axois rquest end

Comment: I have to use Action Dispatcher